# How can I redirect in Boomla (sjs-3)

Tags: boomla

I want to do a simple redirect in Boomla. I know I can set response headers with `response.attrStr()`, but how do I set a status code?

And how can I get an absolute url for a file? Currently I'm using `path()` which should work but I'm not sure it's always safe to use it:

```
response.attrStr('location', fileToRedirect.path())
```

Comment: it's always safe according to http://boomla.com/developers/filesystem/file-node

Answer (score 1):

You can use `statusCode()` to set the status code:

```
response.statusCode(302)
response.attrStr('location', fileToRedirect.path())
```